# pass mouse hover event to lower layer while overlay div elements which has a menu remains clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a canvas with a mouse hover animation on it and above that an overlay which contains a menu. what I want to achieve is to pass on the mouse hover event to the canvas even while I am hovering on the menu.
right now I have it working partly,

I have currently solved this problem partly by using CSS property `pointer-events: none` in the div containing the menu and auto in the clickable list menu elements but while hovering over the menu, the lower canvas doesn't detect the mouse as it has its focus on the menu list child which is set to auto in the mouse pointer events.

How can I allow the above menu to remain clickable while passing on the hover event to the lower canvas?

Comment: Would putting the canvas with "background-color: transparent" on top of the menu work or would that interfere with the menu clicking?

Comment: it would interfere with the menu clicking. the menu has to be the at the top layer for being able to listen to the pointer events.

Comment: Are you currently detecting the mouse hover through javascript or css :hover?

Comment: i am using js for mouse events in the canvas render script

Comment: the problem seems simple to me but dont know how to approach it. i just need to pass the hover to the canvas layer along with keeping the menu clickable. right now on the menu portion the canvas doesnt detect the mouse events. rest it works with the pointer-events: none; solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery you can say that if you hover over either element then do "something" :

`$('.canvasClassName, .menuClassName').mouseover(function () { /*Canvas Action*/ });`

Where canvas/menu ClassName would be a class of the object. (Using other properties like id is also valid using a # instead of a period)

The hover effect will work if you hover over the canvas or the menu while maintaining the menu's useability.